# Why stock in inventory is becoming negative even if no backorder is set in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Qty for some products is showing in negative. I didn't allowed any backorder but still I got the order for such products.
My magento version is 1.8.1.0.
Can anyone please help me in debugging this issue for why and how stock went into negative even when I didn't allowed for it!

Comment: I suggest looking at the orders / refunds etc that have occured on the product. Remember that it is possible for you to manually set a negative stock in magento. See if you can narrow it down to a specific action by reviewing the orders with it, going one at a time untill you see which action(s) triggered the negative.

Comment: @JohnCuthbert: can you please elaborate a bit the steps to be followed so as to reproduce the stuffs what you said!

Comment: Did you try to add a new product, set stock to 1 and try to order 2 or more? Is it possible to order that product then?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema: Yes, I did tried, but it doesn't allows me to order more then what is available in-stock

Answer (score 0):

Inventory checks are demanded to `Mage_CatalogInventory` module and in particular to `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` methods, triggered by different events.
Check whether some third party module overrides or disables some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen constellations where qty is negative / < zero in a very small amount of client systems that we did not create from the scratch. The problem is, that the products with negative qty are "in stock/available" and can be bought by shop customers.

Instead of hunting down the reason i simply put a trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER negative_stock_to_zero BEFORE UPDATE ON cataloginventory_stock_item 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.qty < 0 THEN
       NEW.qty = 0;
    END IF;
END;//
delimiter;
```

Of course you could also check if backordering is enabled/disabled in the IF-Clause - but thats up to you.